# What does the "bulky" trait mean in Traveller 2ed?

Tags: mongoose-traveller-2

I'm playing Mongoose Traveller 2ed and I'm using the **Core Book**. Could you explain to me what the Bulky trait means for a weapon? I haven't found any explanation in the book.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On page 75 of my "Traveller_2e_Core_Rulebook.pdf", I have:

> **Bulky:** A Bulky weapon has a powerful recoil or is simply extremely heavy – this makes it difficult to use effectively in combat by someone of a weak physical stature. A Traveller using a Bulky weapon must have STR 9 or higher to use it without penalty. Otherwise, all attack rolls will have a negative DM equal to the difference between their STR DM and +1.

This page also lists a "Very Bulky" trait, which requires STR 12 to use effectively.